# What should be the REST endpoint for one-to-one resource?

Tags: rest

I have a system with three resources: `User`, `Cart` and `Address`. The relationship as follows:

`User` 1-to-* `Adress`

`User` 1-to-1 `Cart`

Now the endpoint is pretty straightforward for one-to-many or many-to-many mappings. For example, to retrieve `Address`:

**GET** `/api/users/{userId}/addresses/{addressId}` - single address

**GET** `/api/users/{userId}/addresses/` - all addresses

### Mapping One-to-One resource:

How about the `Cart`. It looks like it should be:

GET `/api/users/{userId}/carts/{cartId}` - Retrieve a single for user

There are two problems:

1. I know cart is one-to-one. Yet, I have to query `/carts`.
2. To get a cart for a user, I need to know its cartId. That is bad.

If I know cart is one-to-one, should I still need to query collection endpoint `/api/users/{userId}/carts`? In this case, I get a JSON list/array and then pick the first item. **But that doesn't feel natural**.

Is there any REST convention that defines an intuitive endpoint for a one-to-one mapped resource?

Can I do something like: `/api/users/{userId}/cart`. Notice the absence of plural (s) in `/cart`.

Comment: The last one (singular) seems the most intuitive. It's like: "here's a user, and this is its cart." That's how the url reads to me.

Comment: Another thing that I have used before is just `/api/cart`. Which cart is determined by the auth token. Similarly, Twitter has a `/me` endpoint that is determined by the auth token.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha, I think both the suggestions are good. But can it really be considered RESTful as the resource is not uniquely identified by unique URI?